# How get total sum of 3 input box values using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to show total sum of values entered in 'txtCal' input boxes in next input box named 'totCal' without refreshing page.

**paper.php**

```
<label>No of Questions - Easy level</label>
<input type="number" class="txtCal" id="input_item" name="level1_no_of_questions" placeholder="No of Questions - Easy level"  onblur="findTotal()" Required/><br />

<label>No of Questions - Intermediate level</label>
 <input type="number" name="level2_no_of_questions" class="txtCal" id="input_item" placeholder="No of Questions - Intermediate level" onblur="findTotal()" Required/><br />

<label>No of Questions - Difficult level</label>
<input type="number" name="level3_no_of_questions" class="txtCal" id="input_item" placeholder="No of Questions - Difficult level" onblur="findTotal()" Required/><br/>

<label>Total No of Questions</label>
<input type="number" name="total_no_of_questions" class="totCal" value="20"  readonly="readonly" id="input_item" placeholder="Total No of Questions max="20"/><br />

<input type="submit" value="Add Exam Paper" name="submit" id="submit"/>

<form/>
```

**Action page**
question.php

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $level1_no_of_questions=$_POST['level1_no_of_questions'];
    $level2_no_of_questions=$_POST['level2_no_of_questions'];
    $level3_no_of_questions=$_POST['level3_no_of_questions'];
    $total_no_of_questions=$_POST['total_no_of_questions'];

$sql2= "INSERT INTO exam_paper (level1_no_of_questions,level2_no_of_questions,level3_no_of_questions,total_no_of_questions) VALUES ('$level1_no_of_questions','$level2_no_of_questions','$level3_no_of_questions','$total_no_of_questions');





         if (mysqli_query($dbcon,$sql2)){

            //Redirection to the this page


            header("Location:paper.php");

            exit();
         }else{ 
            $error=mysqli_error($dbcon);
         }
}   

}  
?>

    <script type="text/javascript">
function findTotal(){
    var arr = document.getElementsByClassName('txtCal');
    var tot=0;
    for(var i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
        if(parseInt(arr[i].value))
            tot += parseInt(arr[i].value);
    }
    document.getElementByClassName('totCal').value = tot;
}

    </script>
```

This is not working..What was the error? I cant use the input id or and name.names goes to sql and id goes to design..

Comment: What mean `not` working ?

Comment: when I put the values into 3 inputs, it doesn't give the total in totalinput field

Comment: It doesn't matter where the fields get their data from; you are only calling the JavaScript through `onblur()`. Do your fields **already** have data in them when you attempt to run the `onblur()`? You could find the error with a simple `console.log()` in that case.

Comment: You should never manually create SQL.  Your code really is an SQL injection attack waiting to happen!  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php

Answer (score 3):

To get the result dynamically, you have to bind `eventListener` to the each `input`.

If you want to display the result inside the `.totCal` element, you have to use it with the index (specify the element), since `getElementsByClassName` returns an array-like object.

```js
var arr = document.getElementsByClassName('txtCal');

function findTotal() {
  var tot = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
     tot += parseInt(arr[i].value);
  }
  document.getElementsByClassName('totCal')[0].value = tot;
}

for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  arr[i].addEventListener('keyup', findTotal);
}
```

```html
<label>No of Questions - Easy level</label>
<input type="number" class="txtCal" id="input_item" name="level1_no_of_questions" placeholder="No of Questions - Easy level" onblur="findTotal()" Required/><br />

<label>No of Questions - Intermediate level</label>
<input type="number" name="level2_no_of_questions" class="txtCal" id="input_item" placeholder="No of Questions - Intermediate level" onblur="findTotal()" Required/><br />

<label>No of Questions - Difficult level</label>
<input type="number" name="level3_no_of_questions" class="txtCal" id="input_item" placeholder="No of Questions - Difficult level" onblur="findTotal()" Required/><br/>

<label>Total No of Questions</label>
<input type="number" name="total_no_of_questions" class="totCal" value="20" readonly="readonly" id="input_item" placeholder="Total No of Questions max=" 20 "/><br />
```

Comment: `Uncaught ReferenceError: findTotal is not defined`

Comment: Make sure you include the script in the `<head>` tag, rather than in the `<body>`; that is likely why your variable is undefined :)

Comment: the error is fixed, but I use the max value for the input"totCal" , When Iclick  the  submit button, the total input<=max value it doesn't validate and not given the error message. why?

Comment: @RavinduTheekshana Button? There's no any buttons in your snippet (:

Comment: @RavinduTheekshana What action do you want when clicking the button?

Comment: the max value is 20. I want the total of 3 input as 20. If less than 20 I want to display an error in html or javascript, How to validate?

Comment: @ Kind user I updated the code with action page "question.php"

Comment: The total question value is 20. I doesn't change, So I want to add input fields numbers that total is getting 20

Comment: @RavinduTheekshana It's much more complex than it was at start. I suggest you to make a new question, drop whole code and tag every used language.

Answer (score 1):

I think code explains itself, ask me if you have questions

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/brunjick/zbf678c8/)

```
<form action="#">
  <label>No of Questions - Easy level</label>
  <input type="number" class="txtCal" id="input_item" name="level1_no_of_questions" placeholder="No of Questions - Easy level" Required/><br />

  <label>No of Questions - Intermediate level</label>
  <input type="number" name="level2_no_of_questions" class="txtCal" id="input_item" placeholder="No of Questions - Intermediate level" Required/><br />

  <label>No of Questions - Difficult level</label>
  <input type="number" name="level3_no_of_questions" class="txtCal" id="input_item" placeholder="No of Questions - Difficult level" Required/><br/>

  <label>Total No of Questions</label>
  <input type="number" name="total_no_of_questions" class="totCal" value="0" id="input_item" placeholder="Total No of Questions" min="20" max="20"/><br />

  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

JavaScript:

```
var totalNo = document.querySelector('[name="total_no_of_questions"]');
var inputSources = [
  document.querySelector('[name="level1_no_of_questions"]'),
  document.querySelector('[name="level2_no_of_questions"]'),
  document.querySelector('[name="level3_no_of_questions"]'),
];

// Set event listeners
inputSources.forEach(function (input) {
  input.addEventListener('blur', findTotal);
});

function findTotal() {
  totalNo.value = inputSources.reduce(function (total, curr) {
    var value = Number(curr.value);

    return total + (isNaN(value) ? 0 : value);
  }, 0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here it is!
The error was in:
`document.getElementsByClassName('total').Value = tot;`
the correct is:
`document.getElementsByClassName('totCal')[0].value = tot;`
thank you

```
<label>No of Questions - Easy level</label>
<input type="number" class="txtCal" id="input_item"     name="level1_no_of_questions" placeholder="No of Questions - Easy level"  onblur="findTotal()" Required/><br />

<label>No of Questions - Intermediate level</label>
 <input type="number" name="level2_no_of_questions" class="txtCal" id="input_item" placeholder="No of Questions - Intermediate level" onblur="findTotal()" Required/><br />

<label>No of Questions - Difficult level</label>
<input type="number" name="level3_no_of_questions" class="txtCal" id="input_item" placeholder="No of Questions - Difficult level" onblur="findTotal()" Required/><br/>

<label>Total No of Questions</label>
<input type="number" name="total_no_of_questions" class="totCal" value="20"  readonly="readonly" id="input_item" placeholder="Total No of Questions max=20"/><br />


    <script type="text/javascript">
function findTotal(){
    var arr = document.getElementsByClassName('txtCal');
    var tot=0;
    for(var i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
        if(parseInt(arr[i].value))
            tot += parseInt(arr[i].value);
    }
    document.getElementsByClassName('totCal')[0].value = tot;
}

    </script>
```